A complex function $f$ whose Jacobian family $Jf_x, x\in \mathbb{R}^2$ is a commuting familly of $2\times 2$ matrices
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be  a  real analytic  function with the following property $$Df(a)Df(b)=Df(b)Df(a)\;\quad \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}^2$$
Does this implies that either $f$ is a  linear map or  $f$ is  a  holomorphic map?
Added Note: According to the  existing answer I realize the initial form of the  question has a negative  answer. Now  let $G$ be the  group of  all (Real analytic) diffeomorphism of  the plane. Is it true to say that every $f\in G$ can be  represented in form of  $f=g_1\circ g_2 \circ \ldots g_n$ for  some  $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and  $g_i\in H$  where $H$ is the subset of  $G$ consist of  all $f\in G$ with $Df(a)Df(b)=Df(b)Df(a)\quad \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}^2$

please avoid "no clue" questions: share your thoughts and attempts.

Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26568, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26565, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478

@AnneBauval  Yes thanks I  think now I apply that: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26569/143009

Better apply the detailed and precise advices of the accepted answer to the same post: Ideally, edits to a question should not invalidate existing answers; if an edit would be that rigorous, it would be better to ask another question.

@AnneBauval  Ok Thanks  I  will ask some  more question in this  context  in some separated post.

Consider $(x, y) \mapsto (x^2, y^2)$. Then $$Df((x, y)) = \begin{pmatrix} 2x & 0 \\ 0 & 2y\end{pmatrix}.$$
This is not a linear function, but as Jacobians are diagonal they commute.
Assuming by holomorphic, you are referring to when f is interpreted as a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, then this function is also not holomorphic as it does not satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations.

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Answering it encourages low-quality questions. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

Is that really $Df$?

I  guess you mean  $(x^2,y^2)$

@AnneBauval  I  do not think that is  a  low  quality question after a modification. For example: a  classification of  all  diffeomorphisms  with that property. Or dynamical classification of  all vector  fields on the plane with that property. So you may reconsider your comment above as a comment with low  flexibility

@AnneBauval  Or in diffeomorphism  case can one  say that this  the class of  all  diffeomorphism with this property generate  the  whole  diffeomorphism group?

@AnneBauval  thank you  I  will revise the  question. But I  beleive that MSE and  MO may  have  a more flexible conduct: helping a question to be improved instead of  immediate "close  vote,"

@AnneBauval  Now  I revise the post. i  would like  to add  some  other related question to the post. But MO&MSE policy require that "1 question / one post". otherwise I  would like to ask thie following question too: is there a  vector  field on the plane with the  mentioned propert which has a "limit  cycle" i.e  isolated periodic orbit

Thanks again for  your  answer. It was essential to  help me that those class(linear and  holomorphic maps are not the  only soltion"  Your answer  help me  to think  to  some generalization as I mentioned in the revise  version. I will ask  some  other  questions in this regard
